# WatchGuard proxy error - header-line too large

Tags: watchguard

When trying to access new threads on a forum, I am receiving the error below.  It seems like post count on the forum may have reached a point that it is generating a HTTP response header that is too large.  Which setting in the WatchGuard HTTP proxy will allow me to fix this issue?

> **Response denied by WatchGuard HTTP proxy.**
>
> Reason: header-line too large line='Set-Cookie:
>   hfthread_lastview=1f2b28063f6e3b509884091e30300fdf83ef1b4aa-174-%7Bi-1678510_i-1331573202_i-1679284_i-1331575394_i-1679388_i-1331579857_i-1678606_i-1332367647_i-1679180_i-1331577384_i-1678922_i-1331582026_i-1676987_i-1331586489_i-1679098_i-1331816934_i-1623517_i-1331662038_i-1675289_i-1332256093_i-1679623_i-1331694065_i-1677395_i-1335538137_i-1273504_i-1334800926_i-283873_i-1335464966_i-1679002_i-1331813695_i-1679798_i-1331753384_i-1679859_i-1331793359_i-1661982_i-1331800672_i-1677724_i-1332176467_i-1675288_i-1334113621_i-1680030_i-1331867479_i-1680019_i-1332359815_i-1671174_i-1331928925_i-1601608_i-1334693087_i-1680222_i-1331923147_i-1679931_i-1331920029_i-1680239_i-1331926457_i-1679896_i-1331934005_i-1679333_i-1332254573_i-1679899_i-1331932170_i-1679096_i-1331930715_i-1680507_i-1332525912_i-1674006_i-1332186832_i-1680742_i-1332176241_i-1680760_i-1332271221_i-1680800_i-1332186663_i-1673835_i-1332263214_i-1676727_i-1332369576_i-1541357_i-1332266634_i-1680403_i-1332264886_i-1680908_i-1332265377_i-'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Watchguard HTTP proxy's maximum line length setting is to small for that response.

If you open the Watchguard HTTP Proxy policy, switch to the "Properties" tab and edit the "Proxy action" you can select "General Settings" under "HTTP Response" and increase the "maximum line length".  Here is a screen shot from WSM 11:

[image]